# ActionScript: How come i cant draw diagonally?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, drawing, arrow-keys

So, I'm learning ActionScript on my own with a book ('Foundation AS3.0 with Flash...').
And I'm stuck on an excercise.
I have to make a drawing app with using the arrowkeys and spacebar.
It doesn't work 100%. I can draw up, down, right, left. Even diagonal, only right-up, and left-down.
Do you guys know where my mistake is? I also want to draw left-up and right-down....
Here's my code so far:

```
package classes{
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;

public class KeyboardDrawing extends Sprite{
    private const PIXEL_DISTANCE_TO_DRAW:uint = 2;
    private var _canvas:Sprite;
    private var _crosshair:Shape;
    private var _xDirection:int = 0;
    private var _yDirection:int = 0;
    private var _isDrawing:Boolean = false;

    public function KeyboardDrawing(){
        _canvas=new Sprite();
        addChild(_canvas);
        _crosshair=new Shape();
        drawCrosshair();
        addChild(_crosshair);
        _canvas.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000);
        stage.focus=_canvas;
        _canvas.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onCanvasKeyDown);
        _canvas.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onCanvasKeyUp);
        _canvas.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onCanvasEnterFrame);
    }

    private function drawCrosshair():void{
        _crosshair.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
        _crosshair.graphics.moveTo(-5, 0);
        _crosshair.graphics.lineTo(6, 0);
        _crosshair.graphics.moveTo(0, -5);
        _crosshair.graphics.lineTo(0, 6);
    }

    private function onCanvasKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        switch(event.keyCode){
            case Keyboard.UP:
                _yDirection = -PIXEL_DISTANCE_TO_DRAW;
                break;
            case Keyboard.DOWN:
                _yDirection = PIXEL_DISTANCE_TO_DRAW;
                break;
            case Keyboard.LEFT:
                _xDirection = -PIXEL_DISTANCE_TO_DRAW;
                break;
            case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                _xDirection = PIXEL_DISTANCE_TO_DRAW;
                break;
            case Keyboard.SPACE:
                _isDrawing = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    private function onCanvasKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        switch(event.keyCode){
            case Keyboard.UP:
            case Keyboard.DOWN:
                _yDirection = 0;
                break;
            case Keyboard.LEFT:
            case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                _xDirection = 0;
                break;
            case Keyboard.SPACE:
                _isDrawing = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    private function onCanvasEnterFrame(event:Event):void{
        _crosshair.x += _xDirection;
        _crosshair.y += _yDirection;
        if (_isDrawing){
            _canvas.graphics.lineTo(_crosshair.x, _crosshair.y);
        }else{
            _canvas.graphics.moveTo(_crosshair.x, _crosshair.y);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you press left then up or up then left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue with the keyboard and certain combinations of keys.

If you change the keys to WASD like so it works fine:

```
private function onCanvasKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    switch(event.keyCode){
        case Keyboard.W:
            _yDirection = -PIXEL_DISTANCE_TO_DRAW;
            break;
        case Keyboard.S:
            _yDirection = PIXEL_DISTANCE_TO_DRAW;
            break;
        case Keyboard.A:
            _xDirection = -PIXEL_DISTANCE_TO_DRAW;
            break;
        case Keyboard.D:
            _xDirection = PIXEL_DISTANCE_TO_DRAW;
            break;
        case Keyboard.SPACE:
            _isDrawing = true;
            break;
    }
}

private function onCanvasKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    switch(event.keyCode){
        case Keyboard.W:
        case Keyboard.S:
            _yDirection = 0;
            break;
        case Keyboard.A:
        case Keyboard.D:
            _xDirection = 0;
            break;
        case Keyboard.SPACE:
            _isDrawing = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Basically it's due to flawed keyboard design that simplifies the wiring at the expense of some key combinations.

I found this article that explains it in full: http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx